# how to get the netbsd precise version about book code Reading

Tags: netbsd

i recently read one Book "CODE Reading The open Source Perspective ", wiki link is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_Reading).

I notice that it use a

**netbsd "netbsd export-19980407"**

as its source to dig into.

My question is how to get the precise version of that netbsd?

So i an get more precise code-relating and field experience when use this book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is an ''export'' it probably means it was a CVS export of the main NetBSD tree.

See: http://netbsd.org/releases/formal.html

A date of 1998 / April / 07 (this is how I read the date of the export) - so that would be a CVS version between NetBSD 1.3.1 and NetBSD 1.3.2.

Make of that what you will, since I am not a NetBSD expert (but I have installed and used it a dozen times already).

FWIW, NetBSD newest version is 6.1 - yes, 1998 *was* 15 years ago, and I was much younger then...